# Why JVM NOT crash after oom?

Tags: java, jvm, oom

This maybe an interesting question to ask. In most cases, we do not want jvm crash.

But sometimes the '**oom-ed but not crash**' jvm process keeps runing, and may return a value with NULL instead of the correct value. For some scenarios sensitive to value accuracy, this is not acceptable.

So is there way to **make jvm DO CRASH after oom**? Like some jvm arguments, or alternative approaches to solving this issue to make scenarios keep accuracy.

Comment: Don’t ask three different question at once.

Comment: If you write code that catches `OutOfMemoryException` and returns `null` instead, you have only yourself to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found related: [Why JVM can recovery from OOM Java heap space by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865015/why-jvm-can-recovery-from-oom-java-heap-space-by-itself)

So, jvm arguments:

```
-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Further, also can run a script:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/dir/oomKillAndRestart.sh"
```

Comment: Next time find the related question **before** asking your duplicate question.